# NoTransporterException when uploading with Gradle to Nexus

Tags: gradle, nexus

I am using Gradle (2.13) and trying to upload the jars into a Nexus (2.13.0-01) repository. When running "gradle uploadArchives", I get the following exception:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':communication-server:uploadArchives'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:241)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:214)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:207)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Could not publish configuration 'archives'
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access http://intra.nexus.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.AbstractMavenPublishAction.publish(AbstractMavenPublishAction.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.MavenDeployAction.publish(MavenDeployAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.AbstractMavenResolver.execute(AbstractMavenResolver.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.AbstractMavenResolver.publish(AbstractMavenResolver.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.AbstractMavenResolver.publish(AbstractMavenResolver.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.BaseMavenDeployer.publish(BaseMavenDeployer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher.publish(DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.publish(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:64)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access http://intra.nexus.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.MavenDeployAction.publishArtifacts(MavenDeployAction.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.AbstractMavenPublishAction.publish(AbstractMavenPublishAction.java:97)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access http://intra.nexus.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:265)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: No transporter factories registered
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:113)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoTransporterException: No transporter factories registered
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:115)
    ... 85 more
```

My gradle configuration (relevant excerpt):

```
//internal nexus repository for dependencies
repositories {
    maven { url "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/central/" }
}

//nexus repo upload
configurations {
    deployerJars
}
dependencies {
    deployerJars "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2"
}
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            configuration = configurations.deployerJars
            repository(url: "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/releases") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: credentials.nexuspdw)
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/snapshots") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: credentials.nexuspdw)
            }
            pom.version = project.version
            pom.artifactId = project.name
            pom.groupId = project.group
        }
    }
}
```

Downloading my dependencies from Nexus works fine. It is also not a credentials/permissions issue since the uploading of the archives works on my local developer machine. What does this error mean and how can I upload my artifacts into Nexus? Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. The issue was cause by an incomplete gradle installation. It was missing the aether-plugins for the repository transport.

I was using the standard Debian gradle 2.13 package (apt-get install gradle), which does not contain all plugins. Removing the installation and using the Ubuntu Gradle 2.13 package fixed my problem.

Comment: I had the same problem with Gradle 3.2.1-1 on Ubuntu 17.04 and fixed it by using Gradle’s original binary release 4.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix this problem in an existing project by using gradle wrapper for build and uploadArchives commands.

./gradlew build

./gradlew uploadArchives

If your project does not have gradle wrapper configured, execute this command to configure gradle wrapper in your projects:

gradle wrapper

this command generates gradlew scripts and some directories with wrapper binaries.

Not sure what was broken and what got fixed but it started working though.
Might be worth a try.

Comment: Made my day! "/gradlew build" had to be done before "./gradlew uploadArchives".